# A program interpretation in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to c and sometimes I get confused by things I see.
I have the following code:

```
int
sstmm_()

{time_t ourtime;
 time(&ourtime);
 return (int)(ourtime&0x00000fff);
}
```

I do not understand what the meaning of `ourtime&0x00000fff` is? 
Is it a pointer yet? What is the rule of `0x00000fff`?
Thank you so much.

Comment: On UNIX-like systems, it gives you a number between 0 and 4095, and te value changes once a second.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : To be clear the _resolution_ of `time_t` is system dependent; the fact that a 12 bit integer has value 0 to 4095 is of course universal.  Even then I have yet to encounter a system where `time_t` is not in seconds, Unix-like or not; it would break a lot of code that made that assumption were it were otherwise.

Comment: @Clifford: No; on UNIX-like systems, POSIX defines `time_t` as an integer type with one second granularity.  That's why the qualifier is there.  I'm not commenting about other system types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I think we are in violent _agreement_ on that point - that is a guarantee that POSIX makes,  my point that it is probably also universal was a side note not a disagreement.   My main point was that your sentence order rather implied that the 0 to 4095 range was system dependent.  I was clarifying that the dependency applies only to the resolution.

Comment: Ok.  I see.  That's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` does not refer to address-of in this case like you probably are confusing it with, but bitwise AND.

The bitwise AND operation takes one left hand side parameter and one right hand side parameter, compares them at the bit level (i.e. the 1s and 0s) and returns a value representing which positions in the LHS and the RHS *both* have a 1.  For example, comparing 6 (binary `0110`) and and 3 (binary `0011`) would give us binary (`0010`), which is 2 in base 10.

Showing our work:

```
0110
0011
----
0010
```

The second-rightmost position is the only place where the two values have a 1 in common, so that's the only place where we get a 1 after bitwise-ANDing them.

Since the right-hand side of that operation is `0x00000fff`, what that operation is doing is taking the parameter `ourtime` and only returning the least significant 12 bits (since `0xF` is `1111` in base 2).

Showing our work again:

```
(ourtime has unknown 0s and 1s.)
00000000000000000000111111111111
```

Since the most significant 20 bits of the right hand side are zeroes, and the least significant 12 bits are all ones, the return value is obviously whatever was in the least significant 12 bits of `ourtime`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
&
```

stands for bitwise and operation here, it is not related to addresss and pointers

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: ourtime&0x00000fff this statment is doing bitwise and operation on value of ourtime and on 4 byte long value represented in hex as 0x00000fff

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`ourtime` is of type `time_t` which is normally a typedef of `__time_t`

`__time_t` type is in itself not the first thing I would explore if I was new to ANSI C, the standard says it represents the system time since unix epoch, on linux like environment it is usually signed integer, which could be 32 bit or 64 bit long.

In visual c++ it has traditionally been a 64bit unsigned integer.

So, no it is not a pointer, now with the usage of &, if you see integers on both sides then it implies it is being used as a *binary operator*, if you just see it being used with one variable it is used as a *unary operator*. You should check out what are the different types of operators in ANSI C many programming languages use them in a similar fashion, use of &as a unary operator is typical to C/C++ though.

`&ourtime` is evaluating to address of `ourtime`. 
  `ourtime&0x00000fff` is asking for last 3 nibbles of integer `ourtime`.